# How use XPath with Accessibility Service Android to interact with an element?

Tags: android, xpath, ui-automation, accessibilityservice, accessibility

There are several articles/tutorials to use Accessibility service on Android to find elements by id/text but there is None (that I could find) which makes use if XPath.

As far as my understanding goes, Accessibility service would take a snapshot of the current ui hierarchy with corresponding attribute and then would search the id/text.

This is significantly slower than having a direct XPath to the element we already have knowledge of - no need to take snapshot of whole ui or search for text in it. (Please correct me if I'm wrong) and can even interact when the item is below the screen; i.e. it has potential to click item when it's not visible yet and will be so after scrolling.

Android does have support of javax.XPath https://android-doc.github.io/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html but I couldn't find any sample to try it on.

Any link/resource/guidance will be appreciated. Use of external libraries is fine as well assuming it doesn't hinder performance. Idea is to click an element (I have XPath for it) *as soon as* it is inflated/rendered in apps making use of some kind of webview element.

Comment: To my understanding XPath is for parsing XML data and if you are running an [Accessibility Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service) you are dealing with a representation of the Android view hierarchy (as a tree of nodes). Also Java/Kotlin listview/recycleviews dynamic and only keep 1 or 2 extra items for performance reasons, so they don't really exist off screen.

Comment: AFAIK almost the same as the screen size can hold views are held in Cache. For recyclerview, it can be configured https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/recyclerview/widget/RecyclerView#setitemviewcachesize However, the app I want it for is sure to have it off-screen BUT accessible. I saw a proprietary code which is working fine. I used some other apps (Tasker) which offers accessibility feature and to find element by Text or so. They also find it but while trying click coordinates, it fails because the coordinates returned are virtual/off-screen.

Comment: The other options I found - Selenium, Appium, UIAutomator - are for testing use case. Based on my research so far, they can't be used in an APK file. I'd be fine running any script file (maybe like python script as in asset file within the apk itself provided there are ways to run them).